# Creating a wired connection b/w two vms in vmware

Tags: networking, configuration, interface, vmware

I was just curious if i can connect any two interfaces of any two vms running on the same box using vmware player as if the two interfaces were connected by network wire. I need this setup for simulating some networking test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under workstation you can create very easily what you're after, however, in player, if you select host only there would be 3 things on the network, the host, and the 2 guests.

Comment: how do we do it in vmware workstation, i have just configured two vms in vmware workstation. ?

Comment: Look at http://pubs.vmware.com/ws8/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=using_ws/GUID-DEE1E2F1-5DA4-4C83-B7C5-A1165C84C757.html specifically the chunk about lan segments.

Comment: Thanks for referring to workstation. just explored the option of lag segment in it :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason of down voting.
Anyway i think that creating one more virtual network like vmnetX and then let the two interfaces connect to the same will solve the problem. Please rectify if i am wrong.

P.S: It is obvious you cannot connect the two vms using 'Wire' :)